# Compile c# code from file on memory

Tags: c#, memory, compilation, runtime-compilation

I want to compile my codes from a file straight into memory (*Runtime-Compilation* or *RunPE method*).

This is the code i use:

```
var param = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            IncludeDebugInformation = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true
        };
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
        param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");

        var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        // The file contaning the codes is here
        var results = codeProvider
            .CompileAssemblyFromFile(param, @"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\code.txt");

        if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            foreach (var error in results.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("Program");
        }
```

This will give me no errors in debugg but Not working too. Just in debugging output im seeing this:

> Loaded '3kp0asrw'. Module was built without symbols.

Other things looks fine.

And this is the code in **code.txt** file that suppose to simply write 3 lines of text and show a message in console:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\writeHere.txt", lines);
        Console.WriteLine("Some Random Text!");
    }
}
```

**Question**: What i am missing here? Do You know any other way to run code from file or source straight in memory (AKA RunPE methods)? Can you show me a simple example?

**Note**: I want to do it for much bigger code and Automate it for later uses, like what .net crypters do in stub files, no need for specifying class name and ... every time. Is it possible?

Comment: My guess is that compiling and *running* are two separate things here.  I'm not familiar with the API, but I would check for a complete example that both compiles and runs the code.

Comment: try reading http://headsigned.com/article/csharp-scripting-example-using-csharpcodeprovider

Answer (score 3):

I recently did the same ,You can update the following according to your requirement ,

```
string[] code = {
                                "using System; using System.Data"+
                                "namespace CodeFromFile"+
                                "{"+
                                "   public class CodeFromFile"+
                                "   {"+
                                "       static public int Add(int a ,int b)"+
                                "       {"+
                                "           return a+b;
                                "       }"+
                                "   }"+
                                "}"
                                    };
```

And pass this code to

```
static int CompileAndRun(string[] code)
    {

        CompilerParameters CompilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
        string outputDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        CompilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
        CompilerParams.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
        CompilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
        CompilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";

        string[] references = { "System.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
        CompilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);

        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults compile = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(CompilerParams, code);

        if (compile.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            string text = "Compile error: ";
            foreach (CompilerError ce in compile.Errors)
            {
                text += "rn" + ce.ToString();
            }
            throw new Exception(text);
        }

        Module module = compile.CompiledAssembly.GetModules()[0];
        Type mt = null;
        MethodInfo methInfo = null;

        if (module != null)
        {
            mt = module.GetType("CodeFromFile.CodeFromFile");
        }

        if (mt != null)
        {
            methInfo = mt.GetMethod("Add");
        }

        if (methInfo != null)
        {                
            return (int)methInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { 5,10});
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Source : [Compiling and Running code at runtime](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/) and [Dynamically Compiling C#](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dynamically_compiling.shtml)

Comment: Tried this and worked with your Example but this doesn't work with bigger codes. Does it ? I stored my code from file to a `string[]` but does not work with, think it needs a lot of tweaks.

Comment: is it throwing some exception ?

Comment: place a break point at                                                                                         `if (compile.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            string text = "Compile error: ";
            foreach (CompilerError ce in compile.Errors)
            {
                text += "rn" + ce.ToString();
            }
            throw new Exception(text);
        } `                                                                                                             this will confirms either code written in file is compiling successfully or not.

Comment: No error or exception, can you do it for files ? im changing `CompileAssemblyFromSource` to `CompileAssemblyFromFile` and further changes but again no errors and nothing will happen.

Comment: I think problem is with code you are reading from file. If you can try with executing the working example from file ?

Comment: Used your code in a file and it worked but mine is not working.

Comment: Means your code is having some issues, add your code in chunks, and keep an eye on responses... :)

Comment: I think the problem is with specifying `module.GetType("type");` and `mt.GetMethod("Main");`

Comment: i think these two lines are specific to his own code, so you can exclude them

Comment: Please update the code to look for your method(that is written in your file) , I simply shared the working example.